# Set Visual Studio document tab colour based on folder or show folder path

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, ide, editor

I'm doing an ASP.Net Core MVC project involving a lot of Controllers and Areas.

I often need to open anything from 3-5 copies of files with the same name - e.g. index.cshtml or similar from different views.

It is getting really annoying to work out which is which or just general quick management.

I've looked and am coming up blank - I've seen productivity power tools, but, all of these are within the same project.

Can anyone recommend anything here?

Answer (score 0):

One way to see the full path would be within Visual Studio, by pressing

```
CTRL + Tab
```

You get a menu with all the open files. At the bottom it shows the file path of the highlighted file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension with **Disambiguator** add-in that detects when two or more tabs have the same title and adds Visual Studio folder or project to titles for these tabs. And you can assign colors to tabs based on file path.

Comment: Note that this extension is not free.